# Cannot login as another user account or using fast user switch on Windows 8, after uninstalling Cisco VPN

Tags: windows

I am using Windows 8 and trying to restore the fast user switch feature and/or the normal login screen where I can login to another user account.   These two features are killed by the CISCO VPN Networking client software.  I followed some Googled help and non working for me.  I have ensured that the "Hide Entry Points for Fast User Switch" is disabled.

After I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, I could see the Switch User, but when I clicked  on it, the screen went blank a few seconds and then returned back to the current user's avatar and with an password entry.  No other user icons appeared.

Basically, I cannot switch or login to another user account.

Any solution to fix this for Windows 8 would be great!